# Not able to set property on mock

Tags: c#, moq

I am trying to set a property on a mock by calling a method on it which sets the property value.

```
MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
Mock<IMockedClass> myMock = new Mock<IMockedClass>();
myMock.SetupAllProperties();

myMock.Object.MethodWhichSetsProperty(myObject);
```

Now I am expecting myMock.Object.MyProperty to be set to myObject, but its not since MethodWhichSetsProperty is never actually called when setting a breakpoint in the actual class that was mocked.

I have also tried

```
myMock.SetupGet(x => x.MyProperty).Returns(myObject);
```

But the property just returns null when used afterwards.

The class that is being mocked:

```
public class MockedClass : IMockedClass
    {
        public MyObject MyProperty { get; private set; }
        
        public MockedClass()
        {
            
        }
        
        public void MethodWhichSetProperty(MyObject myObject)
        {
            MyProperty = myObject;
        }
    }
```

Comment: A [mre] would probably be both helpful and easy to construct.

Comment: Note that your mock contains no reference whatsoever to `MockedClass` (obviously, as it's mocking the interface implemented, not the class) so it should hardly come as a surprise that `MockedClass.MethodWhichSet[s]Property` is not called. Either your mock should mock the concrete class and use `CallBase`, or else what you actually want is a mock that is implemented by wrapping a `MockedClass` instance (Moq won't do that for you). Of course, simply providing a mocked implementation of `MethodWhichSetsProperty` would also do (if it's part of the interface, which you don't show).

Comment: Thanks that sounds reasonable that there is no reference, even though im not really able to grasp how to try your suggestions.

Comment: Moq is a great library with some nice features that help especially in advanced scenarios, but its interface has a bit of a learning curve. You may find NSubstitute easier to work with, in that uses a bit less magic (disclaimer: I have no personal stake in promoting either library).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set up `MethodWhichSetsProperty` for the mocked class.

Something like this should work:

```
MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
myMock.SetupGet(x => x.MyProperty).Returns(myObject);
myMock.Setup(x => x.MethodWhichSetsProperty(It.IsAny<MyObject>())).Callback(objectToAssign => myProperty = objectToAssign);
```

Update with example for multiple arguments:

```
MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
myMock.SetupGet(x => x.MyProperty).Returns(myObject);
myMock.Setup(x => x.MethodWhichSetsProperty(It.IsAny<MyObject>(), It.IsAny<MyObject>(), It.IsAny<MyObject>()))
    .Callback<MyObject, MyObject, MyObject>((myObject1, myObject2, myObject3) => 
    { 
        //Do whatever you want in here e.g.
        myProperty = myObject1.Number + myObject2.Number + myObject3.Number;
    });
```

Comment: Do you know how to set up the callback if MethodWhichSetsProperty takes multiple arguments?

Comment: Added an update

Comment: You're missing some parentheses here in the `Callback`

Comment: @Jamiec, you're right. Have updated to include them

Comment: I will accept this as the answer even though I cant get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Your class has an implementation (ie, when calling `MethodWhichSetProperty` it internally sets a property) - but you're not mocking the class you're mocking the *interface* - and that interface knows nothing of your class implementation.

---

```
myMock.SetupGet(x => x.MyProperty).Returns(myObject);
```

This should absolutely work though, and can easily be demonstrated: https://dotnetfiddle.net/kUSkFl

Comment: Yes it works in this demo you posted, but in my actual program the property is still null though.

Comment: After leaving the computer for 30 minutes this now started working with no changes to my code... pranked by visual studio I guess.